# Is it possible to customize JMX beans UI ?

Tags: java, jmx

I wanted to know if it is possible to customize JMX beans UI elements, The text box is too small, I wanted to change it's size or override it to be a Textbox instead.

Comment: JMX beans don't have UI elements.  So I guess the answer is no.

Comment: What program do you use?  jconsole? visualvm?